# non-texttt underscores in alltt with underscore package also enabled

Tags: typewriter

The following gives me strange raised dots instead of underscores inside the `alltt` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{underscore}
\begin{document}

\textsf{This_is_fine}

\begin{alltt}
\textsf{This_is_not}
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way around this?  If I use `\textrm` instead of `\textsf` the problem is the same.  However, `\texttt` works.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `underscore` works by making `_` an active character, but this setting is overridden in the `alltt` package, which instead sets `_` to a printable character.

### Solution 1

Reinstate the activeness of `_` in `alltt`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\alltt{\catcode`\_=\active}
\begin{document}
\textsf{This_is_fine}

\begin{alltt}
\textsf{This_is_not}
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```

### Solution 2

Load the `fontenc` package, so that the printable underscore prints something good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{underscore}
\begin{document}
\textsf{This_is_fine}

\begin{alltt}
\textsf{This_is_not}
\end{alltt}

\end{document}
```